# i try to run jar file of game but it is not running showin jni erro has occured

Tags: file, swing, class, jar, program-entry-point

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ct0N.png)
i created jar file of snake game. in eclipse  snake game is running properly but after creating jar file it  s not running as expected

i am expecting it should run after createting jar file of game

Comment: What are the JDK and JRE versions in your system? It might be that your system has an older JRE version installed than your JDK,

Comment: i am using eclipse 2021-09  and jdk 1.8.0_291 version installed on my pc then what is problem  after creating jar file it should run but it is nor running

Comment: i am using eclipse 2021-09  and jdk 1.8.0_291 version installed on my pc then what is problem  after creating jar file it should run but it is not running i think jre is also 1.8.0_301